# AWS CodeArtifact is returning 401 in CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codeartifact

My project uses a library from AWS CodeArtifact.  I can fetch the library and build the project in my local and in the github build.  When the AWS CodePipeline runs in our Dev environment, CodeArtifact returns a 401 when trying to access the library.

I updated the IAM role running the Pipeline so that it has these actions:

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
```

I updated the Repository Policy to include this IAM role.  The Repository Policy has these actions:

```
                "codeartifact:DescribePackageVersion",
                "codeartifact:DescribeRepository",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionReadme",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionAssets",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionDependencies",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:ListPackages",
                "codeartifact:PublishPackageVersion",
                "codeartifact:PutPackageMetadata",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository",
                "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken"
```

My build.gradle is using the repository as described here and works in my local this way - https://medium.com/@chauyan/use-aws-codeartifact-in-your-project-7bf5d3e0d3dc

I'm guessing it has to do with the way the library was published, maybe it doesn't have the right permissions, but I don't see that the permissions are changeable here.  Why am I getting a 401 from CodeArtifact when trying to build the project in CodePipeline?

Comment: Does NPM CLI have the authentication token for CodeArtifact? Check `~/.npmrc`

Answer (score -3):

You have to publish to maven central

Comment: This is an internal library, published to codeartifact

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).